# Laravel - Get Property of object

Tags: php, laravel

I have an object named `$shop` of the class `App\Models\Shop` which extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

It has a property named `attributes`

[image: SHOP]

I need to load that property into a variable. The model has no getter for that property.

The class `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` has no getter either. All it has is a `__get()` method.

I tried to load the property like so:

```
$x = $shop->__get("attributes");
```

but it returns "null".

Comment: Why not add a getter to the model for a **proper** way to access that property?

Comment: `$shop->getAttributes()`?

Comment: `$shop->attributes;` if the property is accessible.

Comment: @NicoHaase It is third party code.

Comment: @TimuranBicer It is not; `dd($shop)` shows `#attributes`, which is a private member (I think; I see `+exists: true` too; been a while since I looked at what `+` and `#` mean there). And due to Laravel's model magic, `$shop->attributes` returns `null`, unless `shops` has an `attributes` column (which would be pretty bad). So yeah, `->getAttributes()` would be correct, since Model has that getter defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ways that the Model provides you with access are:

```
 // Using attribute name directly
 $x = $shop->attribute;

 // Getter method
 $x = $shop->getAttribute("attribute");
```

In the case of using the first option, I recommend updating your class's phpdoc with @property to help the IDE

```
/**
 * @property string $name
 * @property int $age
 */
class NameClass {
   protected $fillable = [
     'name',
     'age'
   ];
}
```